# numpy polyfit yields nonsense

Tags: python, numpy, data-fitting

I am  trying to fit these values: [image: Values to fit]

This is my code:

```
  for i in range(-area,area):
    stDev1= []
    for j in range(-area,area):
        stDev0 = stDev[i+i0][j+j0]
        stDev1.append(stDev0)
    slices[i] = stDev1
fitV = []
xV = []

for l in range(-area,area):
    y = np.asarray(slices[l])
    x =  np.arange(0,2*area,1)

for m in range(-area,area):
        fitV.append(slices[m][l])
        xV.append(l)


fit = np.polyfit(xV,fitV,4)
yfit = function(fit,area)

x100 = np.arange(0,100,1)

plt.plot(xV,fitV,'.')
plt.savefig("fits1.png")

def function(fit,area):
   yfit = []
   for x in range(-area,area):
       yfit.append(fit[0]+fit[1]*x+fit[2]*x**2+fit[3]*x**3+fit[4]*x**4)
   return(yfit)

i0 = 400
j0 = 400
area = 50 
stdev = 2d np.array([1300][800]) #just an image of "noise" feel free to add any image // 2d np array you like.
```

This yields:
[image: Wrong fit, in green are the same values I plotted in image 1]

obviously this is completly wrong?
I assume I miss understand the concept of polyfit? From the doc the requirement is that I feed it with with two arrays of shape x[i] y[i]? My values in

```
  xV = [ x_1_-50,x_1_-49,...,x_1_49,x_2_-50,...,x_49_49]
```

and my ys are:

```
  fitV = [y_1_-50,y_1_-49,...,y_1_49,...y_2_-50,...,y_2_49]
```

Comment: Can you provide the input data?

Comment: We don't know `area`, `stDev`, `i0`, `j0`

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand your program. In the future, it would be helpful if you were to distill your issue to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But here are some thoughts:

1. It seems, in your data, that for a given value of *x* there are multiple values of *y*. Given (*x*,*y*) data, `polyfit` returns a tuple that represents a polynomial *function*, but no function can map a single value of *x* onto multiple values of *y*. As a first step, consider collapsing each set of *y* values into a single representative value using, for example, the mean, median, or mode. Or perhaps, in your domain, there's a more natural way to do this.
2. Second, there is an idiomatic way to use the pair of functions `np.polyfit` and `np.polyval`, and you're not using them in the standard way. Of course, numerous useful departures from this pattern exist, but first make sure you understand the basic pattern of these two functions.

   a. Given your measurements *y_data*, taken at times or locations *x_data*, plot them and make a guess as to the order of the fit. That is, does it look like a line? Like a parabola? Let's assume you believe your data to be parabolic, and that you'll use a second order polynomial fit.

   b. Make sure that your arrays are sorted in order of increasing `x`. There are many ways to do this, but `np.argsort` is a easy one.

   c. Run `polyfit`: `p = polyfit(x_data,y_data,2)`, which returns a tuple containing the 2nd, 1st, and 0th order coefficients in `p`, `(c2,c1,c0)`.

   d. In the idiomatic use of `polyfit` and `polyval`, next you would generate your fit: `polyval(p,x_data)`. Or perhaps you want the fit to be sampled more coarsely or finely, in which case you might take a subset of `x_data` or interpolate more values in `x_data`.

A complete example is below.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# these are your measurements, unsorted
x_data = np.array([18, 6, 9, 12 , 3, 0, 15])
y_data = np.array([583.26347805, 63.16059915, 100.94286909, 183.72581827, 62.24497418,
                   134.99558191, 368.78421529])

# first, sort both vectors in increasing-x order:
sorted_indices = np.argsort(x_data)
x_data = x_data[sorted_indices]
y_data = y_data[sorted_indices]

# now, plot and observe the parabolic shape:
plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'ks')
plt.show()

# generate the 2nd order fitting polynomial:
p = np.polyfit(x_data,y_data,2)

# make a more finely sampled x_fit vector with, for example
# 1024 equally spaced points between the first and last
# values of x_data
x_fit = np.linspace(x_data[0],x_data[-1],1024)

# now, compute the fit using your polynomial:
y_fit = np.polyval(p,x_fit)

# and plot them together:
plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'ks')
plt.plot(x_fit,y_fit,'b--')
plt.show()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so my issue is that I have multiple values y's to x. Taking the average is a nice work around but im not sure if that really is equal to a least squares of the mapping I have here (I am not a mathematician but if I recall correctly a function is exact, mappings however can have multiple values of x->y(x). So I guess I am in fact trying to fit a polynomial to a mapping , again its been a long time since i was introduced to functions, maps and their theory :( )

Comment: The terms 'map' and 'function' are more or less interchangeable, with some discipline-specific constraints. It doesn't matter what you call it; the relationship you have plotted is indeterminate: a given value of x yields many values for f(x), and no polynomial can describe it. There's probably a way to jitter the x values and avoid overfitting by using a suitably low-order polynomial, but the LSE would effectively be averaging your f(x) values.